# How to get list of UID that access network, in android

Tags: java, android, android-2.2-froyo, uid

How can I get the list of UID (the list of apps installed in Android ) device.

Answer (score 2):

The UID of an application can be found in the `ApplicationInfo` class. Fetch it for all the applications on a device like this:

```
List<ApplicationInfo> appsInfo = context.getPackageManager()
     .getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_UNINSTALLED_PACKAGES);
```